# MySql FullTextSearch in Boolean mode returning returning results shorter than ft_min_word_len

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I am using Mysql FTS query as below in Boolean Mode

```
SELECT org.org_name FROM org 
WHERE MATCH org.org_name AGAINST ('an*' in BOOLEAN MODE);
```

and this gives me the following result

```
+--------------------------+
| org_name                 |
+--------------------------+
| Chairs and Table Company |
| and                      |
+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, my understanding is that all results less than ft_min_word_len are ignored and in my case, ft_min_word_len is 4 as shown in the below results from this query (**show variables like 'ft%';)**

```
+--------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name            | Value          |
+--------------------------+----------------+
| ft_boolean_syntax        | + -><()~*:""&| |
| ft_max_word_len          | 84             |
| ft_min_word_len          | 4              |
| ft_query_expansion_limit | 20             |
| ft_stopword_file         | (built-in)     |
+--------------------------+----------------+
```

I am wondering why the results like '**and**' are being returned if my understanding is correct. Thanks.

Comment: Is your table using InnoDB? The parameters you show here relate to MyISAM tables. See this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size

Comment: I am using InnoDB - checked using SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `Name` = 'org';

Comment: ok got it - the innodb_ft_min_token_size   is 3. If i added another value 'an' in the db, that doesn't come up !! Thanks - if you put that as an answer i could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FULLTEXT searching is available in both InnoDB and MyISAM tables. But, they have different sets of variables controlling them, for example.

```
MyISAM                   InnoDB
ft_min_word_len     innodb_ft_min_token_size
ft_max_word_len     innodb_ft_max_token_size
```

`SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'tablename'` shows you the table's engine.

[This may be helpful reading](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size).